# Using styled-components on react-native, how can I calc the height of a component?

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

Using styled components I need to calc the height of a component based on screen size, something like this:

```
const ForgotPasswordContainer = styled.View`
   height: calc(100% - 20px);
`;
```

Using like this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Styled-components does not support percentage based values on height. Use vh (percentage of height of screen) or vw (percentage of width of screen) to make it relative to screen size.

```
const ForgotPasswordContainer = styled.View`
    height: calc(100vh - 20px);
`;
```

---

### Note

According to the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native) v2 supports percentages

---

### Edit

Upon further inspection I noticed that even for v2+ percentages do not work on height, but do work on width. So you still need to use the vh/vw or flex to have percentage based height on v2+.

---

### Edit #2

Upon even further inspection 1.4 supported percentage on width but not on height. It seems to me that styled-components is just weird.